# Modal Pop ups in SharePoint Online

Tags: javascript, html, css, sharepoint, modal-dialog

Is it possible to just code in some modal popups with buttons through client- facing SharePoint online, e.g. editing the source or using a script/content editor.

If yes, can I just use html, css, javascript to implement them in either source/script/content editor?

Comment: modal dialogs can open custom pages or can be filled with HTML code, so the answer is yes.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So I done that and have a button which opens a modal but it is working intermittently, it either doesn't open the modal or causes the page to refresh once opening the modal. Any ideas to sort this?

Comment: show your code (html button markup and js)

Comment: Solved it. I think in SharePoint online html buttons default to submit buttons so adding type='button' to the <button> solved it